# Conditionally include attribute is create method - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

What would be the best way of conditionally including an attribute in a `create` (or any `method(attr, attr, attr)` style method)?

```rb
@user = User.find_by_name("Sam") # <- might not exist

Store.create(
  name: "Some Store",
  email: "store@example.com",
  user_id: @user.id if @user.present? # <- CONCEPT ONLY - Should be added if condition is true to prevent error
)
```

the line `user_id: @user.id` throws an error if `@user` wasn't found and is therefore `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most minimal change I could make for your code to work is:

```
Store.create(
  name: "Some Store",
  email: "store@example.com",
  user_id: @user&.id
)
```

This is using the safe navigation operator (`&.`) to "ignore method calls" on `nil` values.

However, why are you fetching a possibly-nil object and then trying to call a method on it? Given the context of your original post, you could instead just do:

```
Store.create(
  name: "Some Store",
  email: "store@example.com",
  user: @user
)
```

This will work fine, regardless of whether or not the `@user` exists.

...Or perhaps even, what you really intend to do is something like:

```
Store.create(
  name: "Some Store",
  email: "store@example.com",
  user: User.find_or_create_by(name: 'Sam')
)
```

Comment: Your second two options are the best ones because they re-use the `if` statement that ActiveRecord already provides.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot that `.create()`'s argument is a shortcut for a hash. Make the hash explicit:

```
hash = {
  name: "Some Store",
  email: "store@example.com"
} 
hash[:user_id] = @user.id if @user.present?
Store.create(hash)
```

Another option is to pass `.create` a block:

```
Store.create do |s|
  s.name = "Some Store"
  s.email = "store@example.com"
  s.user_id = @user.id if @user
end
```